# Find a nonzero vector h in C[0; 1] that is orthogonal to f.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis

Consider the space of continuous functions from $[0,1]$ taking values in $\mathbb R$. We define the inner product $\langle f,g\rangle$ to be the integral $\int_0^1f(x)g(x)dx$.

I need to find a nonzero vector $h$, in the space of continuous functions in $[0,1]$, that is orthogonal to $f$ (ie. a function $h$ such that $\langle f,h\rangle=0$).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: Since $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is an inner product, you just need to find some other function linearly independent from $f$, such as $f^2$, and work with the orthogonal projection. The orthogonal projection of $f^2$ on $f$ is $u=\frac{\langle f,f^2\rangle}{\langle f, f\rangle}f$, then the vector $f^2-u$ is orthogonal to $f$.

Comment: Try $h(x)=a+bx$.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways doing this. One way is to take $g(x)=(x+c)f(x)$ and solve for the constant $c$ from the equation  $\int_0^{1} f(x) g(x) \, dx=0$.  This gives $c=(-\int xf^{2}(x)\, dx) /(\int f^{2}(x)\, dx)$. The function $g$ is non-zero because $(x+c)f(x)\equiv 0$ implies $f(x)=0$ whenever $x \neq -c$ and continuity of $f$ implies $f \equiv 0$. Note that the denominator can be $0$ only when $f\equiv 0$ in which case we can take $g\equiv 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u,v$ be any two linearly independent elements of $C[0,1]$ (not hard to find, the space is infinite-dimensional -  what a bout $u(x)=1$ and $v(x)=x$?). The we have a linar map $\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R$, $(\alpha,\beta)\mapsto \langle \alpha u+\beta v,f\rangle$, which must have a nontrivial element $(\alpha,\beta)$ in its kernel. Take $g=\alpha u+\beta v$ (whis is non-zero because $u,v$ are linearly independent).

Apparently, this method can be extended to find non-zero $g$ with $\langle g,f_1\rangle=\ldots=\langle g,f_n\rangle=0$ by starting with $n+1$ instead of two linearly independent functions.